# LUA - Create Meta Table with every sub table beeing a meta table again

Tags: lua, metatable

but this will get confusing for sure.

I'm still very new to LUA and one thing i haven't worked much yet with is metatables.

I need to find a way to create a meta table which runs a function on editing values. This is not a problem if i stay on "one level", so the first index. Then i can simply use the __newindex to run it. But what i'm trying to do is to run the function whenever *any value* is changed.

This would require some way to set any table inside the metatable to be again a metatable running the same function as the "main" metatable

In my use case that would be a "save" function:

```
function MySaveFunction(tbl)
   FileSave(my_settings_path, tbl)
end

MyTable = setmetatable()
MyTable.Value = value --> run MySaveFunction(MyTable.Value)

MyTable.SubTable = {} --> run setmetatable() on SubTable
MyTable.SubTable.Value = value --> run MySaveFunction(MyTable.SubTable.Value)

MyTable.SubTable.SubSubTable = {} --> run setmetatable() on SubSubTable
MyTable.SubTable.SubSubTable.Value = value --> run MySaveFunction(MyTable.SubTable.SubSubTable.Value)

MyTable.SubTable.SubSubSubTable = {} --> run setmetatable() on SubSubSubTable
MyTable.SubTable.SubSubSubTable.Value = value --> run MySaveFunction(MyTable.SubTable.SubSubSubTable.Value)
```

Hope someone can help me <.<

Comment: Should `MyTable.Value = value2` invoke `MySaveFunction` again?

Comment: Yes exactly, every edit/change/creation/delete should invoke it

Comment: You need to use a proxy table and travel it with an additional context. Something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63577908/full-path-to-the-required-value/63580842#63580842) should do the job. I'll try it after work if you won't have an answer by then.

Answer (score 2):

First thing to take a note of is that `__newindex` and `__index` metamethods are only triggered when they handle `nil` value in target table. If you want to track every single change, you can't just use `__newindex`, because once you write a value, subsequent calls won't do anything. Instead, you need to use a proxy table.

Another important thing to consider is tracking paths of accessed members.

Last, but not least, you need to remember to use raw access functions like e.g. [`rawget`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-rawget) when implementing your handlers. Otherwise, you may encounter stack overflows or other weird behaviour.

Let's have a trivial example to illustrate the problems:

```lua
local mt = {}
function mt.__newindex (t, key, value)
    if type(value) == "table" then
        rawset(t, key, setmetatable(value, mt)) -- Set the metatable for nested table
        -- Using `t[key] = setmetatable(value, mt)` here would cause an overflow.
    else
        print(t, key, "=", value) -- We expect to see output in stdout for each write
        rawset(t, key, value)
    end
end

local root = setmetatable({}, mt)
root.first = 1                   -- table: 0xa40c30 first   =   1
root.second = 2                  -- table: 0xa40c30 second  =   2
root.nested_table = {}           -- /nothing/
root.nested_table.another = 4    -- table: 0xa403a0 another =   4
root.first = 5                   -- /nothing/
```

Now, we need to deal with them. Let's start with a way to create a proxy table:

```lua
local
function make_proxy (data)
    local proxy = {}
    local metatable = {
        __index = function (_, key) return rawget(data, key) end,
        __newindex = function (_, key, value)
            if type(value) == "table" then
                rawset(data, key, make_proxy(value))
            else
                print(data, key, "=", value) -- Or your save function here!
                rawset(data, key, value)
            end
        end
    }
    return setmetatable(proxy, metatable) -- setmetatable() simply returns `proxy`
end
```

This way you have three tables: *proxy*, *metatable* and *data*. User accesses *proxy*, but because it's completely empty on each access either `__index` or `__newindex` metamethods from *metatable* are called. Those handlers access *data* table to retrieve or set the actual values that user is interested in.

Run this in the same way as previously and you will get an improvement:

```lua
local root = make_proxy{}
root.first = 1                   -- table: 0xa40c30 first   =   1
root.second = 2                  -- table: 0xa40c30 second  =   2
root.nested_table = {}           -- /nothing/
root.nested_table.another = 4    -- table: 0xa403a0 another =   4
root.first = 5                   -- table: 0xa40c30 first   =   5
```

This should give you an overview on why you should use a proxy table here and how to handle metamethods for it.

What's left is how to identify the path of the field that you are accessing. That part is covered in [another answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63577908/full-path-to-the-required-value/63580842#63580842). I don't see a reason to duplicate it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is still a bit confusing and much but it gives me at least a good guidance to figure things out!

Comment: @frenkey, One more thing I think is worth clarifying as what you wrote indicates you may misunderstand it: when you do `setmetatable(a, b)` you assign a table `b` to act as metatable for table `a`. `a` doesn't become a metatable - it has a metatable assigned. Anyway, those aren't the easiest things out there, take your time, read, experiment on your own. Metatables are great fun once you wrap your head around them!

Comment: @frenkey, I updated proxy example to hopefully make it more descriptive, check it out.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to wrap my head around it! I do see the potential of the metatables already, but its just so different to everything else i used before